# How to form array from text field contents, and pass that array as serialized form data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text field: `<input type="text" class="field blink" name="j-state[]" id="j-state"/>`

The data in it will be a comma-separated list of states, e.g. `New York,New Jersey`.

I am using `serialize()` to grab the form's data. I want to form an array of these states, and pass the array along with serialized data.

Can any help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give an example of data that might be in the text field that you want to turn into an array?

Comment: the data in the array is simply names of states as New York,New Jersey

Comment: So the content of the field might be e.g. `New York,New Jersey`?

Comment: Parse the comma separated text to an array? seems pretty basic, am I missing something?

Comment: My main problem is that I want to add array along with serialized data

Comment: Are you using jQuery `.serialize` or something else?

Comment: yes I am using  jQuery .serialize

Comment: how do you use the form data that you get with serialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not want to have to deal with your name with the dash so I renamed it thus:(you can deal with that issue yourself otherwise if you like)

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" class="field blink" name="jstate[]" id="jstate"/>
</form>
```

Get some code from this questions answer: [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

then do this:

```
$('#jstate').val('New Yourk, Fridaay Town,Frenchville');
var jd = $('#myform').serializeObject();
var ms = jd.jstate[0].split(",");
alert(ms[1]);// alerts " Friday Town"
```

You can then use `toJSON()` (google that) to properly form that ms object and send it off - I will leave that exercise to you.

And, last off, a fiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/MHVeC/